# How to format date from date picker angular material in format ('Y-MM-DD')? Reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have tried everything but I am not succeeding. In the example where I do not do the reactive form but the ng-model, it went very easy for me:

```
deliveryDate: moment(this.startDate).format('Y-MM-DD')
```

But in current code in Angular form I Can't change anything. Look my code:

```
   export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'MM/DD',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MM/DD',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};


@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-order',
  templateUrl: './my-order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-order.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    // `MomentDateAdapter` can be automatically provided by importing `MomentDateModule` in your
    // application's root module. We provide it at the component level here, due to limitations of
    // our example generation script.
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})
 resultOfdate: any = MY_FORMATS;


this.getProducts();
this.form = this.fb.group({
  deliveryDate: [moment(this.resultOfdate).format('2020-MM-DD'), Validators.required],  //this is not work format is hard-code on 2020 because deliveryDate from form return current date like a new Date(). this.resultOfdata is
  address: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
  phone: [null, [Validators.minLength(9),Validators.maxLength(19)]],
  city: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
  data: this.fb.array([this.createContact()]),
  note: [null]
});
```

And my template:

```
        <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="resultOfdate"  matInput [matDatepicker]="resultOfdate" placeholder="Choose a date" >
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="resultOfdate" ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #resultOfdate></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
```

I want to send like a 2019-10-10 example

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? I want to understand better, can you improve the question?
And If you could add a stackblitz, it could be helpful.

Comment: i want to format from a given picker instead of the current one Sun Dec 22 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100 to 2019-22-12

Comment: @Pabo can you see my problem ?!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the moment.format in the wrong place.

try it like this, calling your method on dateChange like this:

```
export const MY_FORMATS_ORG = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'MM/DD',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'MM/DD',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-formats-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-formats-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-formats-example.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS_ORG},
  ],
})
export class DatepickerFormatsExampleComponent {
  date = new FormControl(moment());
  dateData: string;

  public setDate(date: string) {
    this.dateData = date ? moment(date).format('Y-MM-DD') : '';
  }
}
```

Check it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-6hjuhq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Also, this:

```
deliveryDate: moment(this.startDate).format('Y-MM-DD')
```

would be wrong, should be something like:

```
deliveryDate: string;
```

and the assignment will be done in the method.

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is maybe help me. I need try this

Comment: deliveryDate: null 
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      deliveryDate: [this.dateData ],
      // moment(this.startDate).format('Y-MM-DD')
      address: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
      phone: [null, [Validators.minLength(9),Validators.maxLength(19)]],
      city: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
      data: this.fb.array([this.createContact()]),
      note: [null]
    });

Comment: look my code i am little confused https://codepen.io/mihaufs/pen/jOEOxRx?editors=1010

Comment: i using     this.form = this.fb.group({
      // deliveryDate: [this.dateData ],
      // moment(this.startDate).format('Y-MM-DD')
      deliveryDate: [this.deliveryDate.value],
      address: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
      phone: [null, [Validators.minLength(9),Validators.maxLength(19)]],
      city: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
      data: this.fb.array([this.createContact()]),
      note: [null]
    });  

How to set FOrmCOntrol here?

Comment: @pabo can you help me? I not using FomControl ? How the fix this?

Comment: Can you make a minimal functional example on stackblitz? Codepen does not execute your code.

Comment: I forgot add  {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS_ORG},
I don;t know how to get value in variable 
set momen(variable).format(....

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: Can you maybe know where is my problem ? 1

Comment: Always my value be or null or moment not work with him

Comment: I might, please reproduce your error on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-6hjuhq (fork it), Reproduce the behavior on your code. Pls

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-fcxmqe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-formats-example%2Fdatepicker-formats-example.component.ts

Comment: I again have any error but I don't know how remove it

Comment: Ok I am deleted all error 
NOw you can see 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-fcxmqe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-formats-example%2Fdatepicker-formats-example.component.html

Comment: answear me and I will give you vote up and check green

Comment: I will check that as soon as my work is done. But I will.